# Is it possible to suppress AgGrid Client-Side data filtering when applying filter?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use React AgGrid to show data that fetched with RTK Query.
Is it possible to suppress AgGrid Client-Side data filtering, especially for build-in AgGrid's filter components, because I do it already on backend with a rtk-query? I don't want to use Server Side Row Model, because it's overhead for my purposes. It's okay for me, that grouping and sorting are on a client side.

Here is example of code:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useImmer({
    finishDateFrom: null,
    finishDateTo: null,
    projectTitle: null,
    projectIds: null,
    managerIds: null,
});


const { data: rowData, isFetching } = useGetGridDataQuery({
    finishDateFrom: filters.finishDateFrom,
    finishDateTo: filters.finishDateTo,
    projectTitle: filters.projectTitle,
    projectIds: filters.projectIds,
    managerIds: filters.managerIds,
});

const handleFilterChanged = (event: FilterChangedEvent) => {
    const filterModel = event.api.getFilterModel();
    setFilters((draft) => {
        draft.finishDateFrom = filterModel?.finishDate?.dateFrom;
        draft.finishDateTo = filterModel?.finishDate?.dateTo;
        draft.projectTitle = filterModel?.projectTitle?.values;
        draft.projectIds = filterModel?.projectIds?.values;
        draft.managerIds = filterModel?.managerIds?.values;
    });
};


return (
    <AgGridReact
        ...
        rowData={rowData}
        onFilterChanged={handleFilterChanged}
    />
);
```

I only found that, it possible to write custom filter component, and always return `'true'` from `doesFilterPass()` function inside it. But I want to use standard AgGrid filter features.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel filtering for all columns

```
const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 150,
    // add this line
    filter: false,
  };
}, []);
```

Relevant column

```
{ field: 'athlete' },
```

Before (filter: true)
[image: Before]

After (filter: false)
[image]

Beware! If you have a custom filter for a column, it will not work. For instance, it will not work if you have something like that in your columnDefs

```
{
  field: 'date',
  filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
  filterParams: filterParams,
},
```

[image: Excluded]

Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/Jrdm7qGFT4M2b8El?preview

Comment: But is it possible to use agDateColumnFilter without filtering rows by AgGrid engine, but get only filter model via onFilterChanged callback?

Comment: You want to fill Ag-Grid filters by your server response?

Comment: I want to Ag-Grid shows filter icon, but doesn't filter rows, when I applied filter. Because rows will be from response.